# How to test webhooks with jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, webhooks

I'm new with JMeter and I get a task on how to get the callback from the system.

I already using a parallel controller but not really understand how to use it.

I have 1 HTTP Requests so when I running with JMeter, status in response data is pending

I expected to get status is a success or failure status from callback after getting pending status

[That I do with jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvHlL.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I think tomorrow I will share on my question

Answer (score 0):

No, JMeter isn't the tool for testing webhooks or responding to postback calls

You can check other solutions as testing webhooks https://webhook.site/

Or mocking API as https://beeceptor.com/

Comment: I was thought about that but I still curious. Thanks for solutions